# Cartesian product of two RDD in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, dot-product

I am completely new to Apache Spark and I trying to Cartesian product two RDD. As an example I have A and B like :

```
A = {(a1,v1),(a2,v2),...}
B = {(b1,s1),(b2,s2),...}
```

I need a new RDD like:

```
C = {((a1,v1),(b1,s1)), ((a1,v1),(b2,s2)), ...}
```

Any idea how I can do this? As simple as possible :)

Thanks in advance

PS: I finally did it like this as suggested by @Amit Kumar:

```
cartesianProduct = A.cartesian(B)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not the dot product, that's the cartesian product.  Use the `cartesian` method:

```
def cartesian[U](other: spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike[U, _]): JavaPairRDD[T, U]
```

> Return the Cartesian product of this RDD and another one, that is, the RDD of all pairs of elements (a, b) where a is in `this` and b is in `other`.

[Source](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.6.2/api/core/spark/api/java/JavaRDD.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like the following:

```
A = {(a1,v1),(a2,v2),...}
B = {(b1,s1),(b2,s2),...}

C = A.cartesian(B)
```

And if you do:

```
C.take(5)
```

You can see that this is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if you are curious on how to do with multiple lists, here's an example in pyspark

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [5,6,7,8]
>>> c = [11,22,33,44,55]
>>> import itertools
>>> abcCartesianRDD = sc.parallelize(itertools.product(a,b,c))
>>> abcCartesianRDD.count() #Test
    60
```