# Spark Scala: Distance between elements of RDDs

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have 2 RRDs with time series. Like

```
rdd1.take(5)

[(1, 25.0)
 (2, 50.23)
 (3, 65.0)
 (4, 7.23)
 (5, 12.0)]
```

and

```
rdd2.take(5)

[(1, 85.0)
 (2, 3.23)
 (3, 9.0)
 (4, 23.23)
 (5, 65.0)]
```

I would like to find the disctance between each element of the first rdd and each element of the second and get next

```
result.take(5)

[((1,1): (25.0-85.0)**2),
 ((1,2): (25.0 - 3.23)**2),
 .....
 ((1,5): (25.0 - 65.23)**2),
 .....
 ((2,1): (50.23 - 85.0)**2),
 .....
 ((5,5): (12.0 - 65.0)**2),
]
```

The number of elements can be from 10 000 to billions.

Please, help me.

Comment: Post duplicated.. see this..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30991302/cartesian-product-of-two-rdd-in-spark

Comment: So what exactly is the question here?

Comment: What are you going to do with the result? If you have billions (10**9) of elements, you will have 10**18 pairs. It's unlikely you can do anything useful with that many, so probably you're going to filter things next?

Comment: In the next I would like to have only top() value of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Mohit is right, you are looking for the cartesian product of your two RDDs, then you should map and compute your distance.

Here is an example :

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(List((1, 25.0), (2, 50.23), (3, 65.0), (4, 7.23), (5, 12.0)))
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(List((1, 85.0), (2, 3.23), (3, 9.0), (4, 23.23), (5, 65.0)))

val result = rdd1.cartesian(rdd2).map {
    case ((a,b),(c,d)) => ((a,c),math.pow((b - d),2))
}
```

Now, let's see how it looks like :

```
result.take(10).foreach(println)
# ((1,1),3600.0)
# ((1,2),473.93289999999996)
# ((1,3),256.0)
# ((1,4),3.1328999999999985)
# ((1,5),1600.0)
# ((2,1),1208.9529000000002)
# ((2,2),2209.0)
# ((2,3),1699.9128999999998)
# ((2,4),728.9999999999998)
# ((2,5),218.1529000000001)
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is [`Cartesian Product`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.6.2/api/core/spark/api/java/JavaRDD.html). This gives you the product (or pairing) between each element of `RDD1` with `RDD2`.

Since you are dealing with billion-size dataset, make sure your infrastructure supports it.

A [`similar question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30991302/cartesian-product-of-two-rdd-in-spark) may help you further.